# Check which RAM slots are empty in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, hardware, ram

My PC has 4 slots to install RAM (memory). I have RAM installed only in the second slot, the rest are empty. This is a Windows PC.

Is it possible to determine which slots have RAM installed from Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Make sure you have `win32api` installed.](https://superuser.com/a/1329256)

```
import win32com.client

strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory")
for objItem in colItems:
    if objItem.BankLabel != None:
        print "BankLabel:" + ` objItem.BankLabel`
```

Code borrowed and excerpted from:
https://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmi/python/0344/

Further reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory

Comment: It's worked. Thanks a lot.